# How to get username in ValidateClientAuthentication method

Tags: oauth-2.0, asp.net-web-api2

In my webAPI application, i used `Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant` for the authentication. The current code working fine with username and password.

Now the application includes multi-tenant so that i added 'clientId' details in the user table. Anyway client details are in another cloud we can call that api to validate the client by passing clientId and password.

To implement this, i used `ValidateClientAuthentication` method to validate the client and `GrantResourceOwnerCredentials` method to verify the user.
This is also fine.

**Problem:**
Basically, i also needs to support old  customers so they does not have client details. So if the user have clientId, we need to validate the client otherwise only validate user.

**Implementation:**

```
        public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
    {
        var userManager = context.OwinContext.GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
        ApplicationUser user = await userManager.FindAsync(context.UserName, context.Password);

        if (user == null)
        {
            context.SetError("invalid_grant", "The user name or password is incorrect.");
            return;
        }


        ClaimsIdentity oAuthIdentity = await user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(userManager,
           OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType);
        ClaimsIdentity cookiesIdentity = await user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(userManager,
            CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);


        AuthenticationProperties properties = CreateProperties(user.UserName,context.ClientId);
        AuthenticationTicket ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(oAuthIdentity, properties);
        context.Validated(ticket);
        context.Request.Context.Authentication.SignIn(cookiesIdentity);
    }

    public override async Task ValidateClientAuthentication(OAuthValidateClientAuthenticationContext context)
    {
        string clientId;
        string clientSecret;
        context.TryGetFormCredentials(out clientId, out clientSecret);

        TenantCloud clientAPI = new TenantCloud();
        context.TryGetFormCredentials(out clientId, out clientSecret);

        if (clientId != null || clientSecret != null)
        {
            var tenantResponseJson = await clientAPI.AuthorizeTenant(clientId, clientSecret).ConfigureAwait(false);
            if (tenantResponseJson == null || (tenantResponseJson != null && tenantResponseJson.AccessToken == null))
            {
                context.Rejected();
                return;
            }
        }
        context.Validated();
        return;
    }
```

Current code works correctly if the user passes client details. But i want to confirm whether user has clientid or not. If user have clientId, it should validate or return error.

To do this, any option to get username from the request so that i can get the corresponding user and check whether the user have clientId or not?

Answer (score 0):

I got solution in 2 ways.

**Solution 1:**

I can check context.ClientId is not null  if user has client id. The update is like below;

```
        public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
    {
        var userManager = context.OwinContext.GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
        ApplicationUser user = await userManager.FindAsync(context.UserName, context.Password);
        if (user == null || user.IsDeleted)
        {
            context.SetError("invalid_grant", "The user name or password is incorrect.");
            return;
        }
        //Ensure that user has client/ tenant. If user have tenant and the tenant is not passed, set the context as rejected.
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(user.ClientId) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(context.ClientId))
        {
            context.SetError("invalid_grant", "The client credentials are incorrect.");
            return;
        }

        ClaimsIdentity oAuthIdentity = await user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(userManager,
           OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType);
        ClaimsIdentity cookiesIdentity = await user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(userManager,
            CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);


        AuthenticationProperties properties = CreateProperties(user.UserName, !string.IsNullOrEmpty(user.ClientId) ? context.ClientId : string.Empty);
        AuthenticationTicket ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(oAuthIdentity, properties);
        context.Validated(ticket);
        context.Request.Context.Authentication.SignIn(cookiesIdentity);
    }
```

**Solution 2:**

This is exactly the answer to the question. I can get the userId using `context.Parameters` in `ValidateClientAuthentication` method itself.

```
var username = context.Parameters.Get("username");
```

Here I can retrieve user (not validating here) and check whether the user have client id. If exist, i need to validate client otherwise rejected.

**I used the solution 1 for the simplicity**. 
Second solution needs take user from the owin context and check the existence.

Thanks.